# Начало предложения с союзов, или Великая тайна русского языка. Почему все так сложно?

Tags: синтаксис, союзы

Пожалуйста, объясните, почему в русском языке предложения не начинают с союзов **И** и **А**?
Например: ***А*** было очень неплохо; ***И*** люди пошли танцевать.

Это что, противоречит правилам русского языка или просто не привилось?
Я еще со школы пытаюсь это выяснить. **А** мне учителя постоянно отвечали общими фразами, типа "это не принято".

Я очень люблю писать с союзами. Мне так нравится, текст по-другому воспринимается.

Comment: Денис, конечно, речь не идет о том, чтобы каждое предложение начинать с союза.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С союза не очень хорошо начинать **повествование**, но это не относится к предложению, которому предшествует контекст (иногда автору нужна пауза или он заканчивает перед этим союзом длинное предложение). Даже в заголовках можно встретить намекающий на что-то большее союз в начале. Например, фильм Феллини "E la nave va" в нашем прокате шёл под названием "А корабль плывёт".

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно почитать лекцию Зализняка для школьников "Об истории русского языка":

> *В бытовом разговоре мы часто отклоняемся от того, как мы должны были бы написать, если бы сдавали редактору свое литературное сочинение. И вы не получили бы одобрения, если бы в вашем школьном сочинении вы начали фразу так: А знаете, что я вчера видел. Между тем начальное а — это совершенно нормальная форма разговорной русской речи: А вот что я вам скажу. А после этого было то-то и то-то. В живой речи с а начинается едва ли не большинство предложений. И это ровно то, что мы наблюдаем в берестяных грамотах. Слово а в начале фразы означает примерно следующее: «Вот что я сейчас вам скажу». Но в нормах церковнославянского языка это слово отсутствовало. Церковнославянская норма его не только не употребляла, но и запрещала употреблять. То есть запрещала, конечно, не в смысле государственного эдикта, а в смысле редакторского давления, которое действует до сих пор. Редактор вам это а зачеркнет и сейчас.*

Comment: У Тургенева не зачеркнет, в художественных текстах присоединительные союзы составляют живую ткань произведения, служат средством связи между предложениями.  Если же вы в деловой речи будете употреблять союз А, то это не есть хорошо, но это означает, что нарушен стиль, грамматика  неверна, а не союз виноват. Зачеркнутый союз ничего не изменит, надо править весь текст.

Comment: Почему весь текст править, так и не понял. Ну да ладно, этовсё спекуляции... Кстати, вы уверены, что подобные А в начале предложений -- это союзы?

Comment: Да, это союзы. Союз в начале предложений -  одно из выразительных средств русского языка.  См. у Валгиной. Виды союзов в сложном предложении.

Answer (score 4):

А кто распространяет мнение, что предложение не может начинаться с присоединительных союзов (в некоторых случаях без такого союза и предложения не построишь)?. Да и классики безо всяких ограничений располагали  союзы И,  НО, А  в начале предложения, например:

А потом показалось и солнце, горячее июльское солнце, под лучами которого мокрая трава точно задымилась. (Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк).

И почему я думаю, что это она? и почему я даже так в этом уверен? (М. Ю. Лермонтов).

И зачем мне церемониться, в самом деле? (И. С. Тургенев).

И он подумал, что это опять был только сон… (В. Г. Короленко).

Но что-то не давало мне спать: достаточно было тонкого напева комара, чтобы очнуться (И. А. Бунин).

Другое дело, что использование союзов должно быть обоснованным и соответствовать их значению. К примеру, вряд ли учителю понравится, если ученик каждое предложение будет начинать с союза А.

Comment: "Другое дело, что использование союзов должно быть обоснованным и соответствовать их значению. К примеру, вряд ли учителю понравится, если ученик каждое предложение будет начинать с союза А."

Избыточность - это всегда плохо. Тут вопросов нет. :-) А по остальному спасибо, успокоили немного.

Comment: Вера, видимо,таким образом учителя учат детей заканчивать мысль.

Comment: Серж, об этом надо спросить учителей, может быть, кто-нибудь откроет педагогическую тайну.

Answer (score 3):

Вопреки распространенному мнению, что с союзов предложения начинать нельзя, предложение с союзов начинают. Синтаксис русского языка гибок и позволяет начинать предложение с любого слова.

Вот правило. Точка ставится перед союзами *а, но, однако* и т. п., если они не связывают в одно целое предложения, а начинают собой самостоятельное предложение.

Обратимся к примерам из художественной литературы.

> На дворе уж восходило солнце, громко пели птицы; слышно было, как в саду шагал садовник и как скрипела его тачка... А немного погодя послышалось мычанье коров и звуки пастушеской свирели. Солнечный свет и звуки говорили, что где-то на этом свете есть жизнь чистая, изящная, поэтическая. Но где она? О ней никогда не говорили Володе ни maman, ни все те люди, которые окружали его.***«Володя» А. П. Чехова.***
>
> Пока осмотрят, одобрят и утвердят цену, пройдут месяцы, да и неизвестно еще, утвердят ли (Тевек).
>
> То телега проедет со скрипом, то раздастся голос какой-нибудь бабы, идущей на рынок ***(Ч.).***
>
> Ни калина не растет меж ними, ни трава не зеленеет ***(Г.).***
>
> Я везде чувствовал связь, соединяющую всё это молодое общество, и с грустью чувствовал, что связь эта как-то обошла меня. Но это было только минутное впечатление ***(Л. Толстой).***

Comment: >> *На дворе уж восходило солнце, громко пели птицы; слышно было, как в саду шагал садовник и как скрипела его тачка... А немного погодя послышалось мычанье коров...*  А вот это совсем не тот союз, о котором речь. Он как бы продолжает предыдущее предложение. Сравните с этим: *А наша кошка родила вчера котят.* Совершенно разные вещи. Посмотрите еще раз у Зализняка: *Слово A в начале фразы означает примерно следующее: «Вот что я сейчас вам скажу»*  И мне совсем не нравится, что его считают союзом. Гораздо больше на частицу похоже.

Comment: В предложениях " А ты как думаешь? А почему не хочешь?" вряд ли можно увидеть тот смысл, которой вкладывает Зализняк.

Comment: Именно тот самый смысл.

Comment: Может, вы и видите этот смысл, но не я!

Answer (score 1):

Начинать предложение с союза - художественный приём "парцелляция". Обычно учителя говорят, что нельзя начинать с союза, потому что, если вы школьник, они оценивают ваше сочинение или какую-либо работу как работу школьника. Мне объяснили, что парцелляция - уровень писателя, поэтому обычному школьнику его запрещают использовать.

Comment: В вопросе было главным — «это... противоречит правилам русского языка или просто не привилось».

Answer (score -1):

Союзы *А, И* в начале предложения выполняют функцию частиц. Они не соединяют и не сопоставляют.