# Можно ли поставить точку?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли писать:

> Посмотрим на Васю. И Петю.

Дело в том, что при очень больших придатках при Васе и Пете, с множественными внутренними и: не хочется связываться с огромным предложением типа

> Посмотрим на Васю который [ ..и ..и ..] и Петю который [ ..и ..и ..]

Вместо этого хочется разделить его на два предложения (при этом не повторяя глагол посмотрим, или лучше повторить?).

> Посмотрим на Васю который [...и ...и ...и...]. И Петю который [...и ...и ...и...].

Можно ли так делать?

Comment: Приведите внятный пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: Посмотрим на Васю который молодой и красивый и Петю не знает совсем и Петю который старый и некрасивый и Васю знает по наслышке, и не любит приводить примеры. То есть без точки предложение сложное для восприятия. Происходит путанница в союзах однородных членах и тому подобном. А точка решает все проблемы.
Имейте ввиду что пример просто для иллюстрации. Меня интересует вопрос в целом: можно или нельзя.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Начало предложения с союзов, или Великая тайна русского языка. Почему все так сложно?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417207/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%92%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb)

Comment: @user190920 - Конечно, путаница будет, если запятые демонстративно игнорировать. А если их поставить - да в нудном месте в нужном месте, никакой сложности не возникнет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Посмотрим на Васю. И Петю.***

Так можно написать. Но, на мой взгляд, текст, в котором вы используете *парцелляцию*, нужно хорошо  продумать, он должен быть выразительным, экспрессивным. Тогда использование этого приёма будет уместным.

**Парцелляция** – это синтаксическая конструкция, в которой представлено разделение целостного текста на отдельные фрагменты, обособленные с помощью пунктуации; это стилистический приём, который используется в художественных, публицистических текстах и не только в них как средство повышения информативности и экспрессивности текстов.

***Все мы жили рядом с ней и не поняли, что есть она тот самый праведник, без которого, по пословице, не стоит село.
Ни город.
Ни вся земля наша.*** (А. Солженицын);